# working with react-native-offline in background

Tags: react-native, redux, asyncstorage, react-native-background-fetch, react-native-offline

I'm trying to find a way to launch actions (redux actions) stored in AsyncStorage by [react-native-offline](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-offline) when the app is in the background.
I've read about Headless JS and react-native-background-fetch but haven't seen the implementation of offline-stored redux actions when the app is in the background.
If anyone had any experience with this I'd be happy for a piece of advice!

Comment: hey, did you figure out this? This is exactly what I am also looking for.